# Audio switching to mono under a certain volume

Tags: windows-10, audio, mono

Since a little time I'm experiencing that my audio on Windows 10 swtiches to mono under around 10% of the maximum volume (it isn't a fixed value, if you lower the volume the threshold lowers in proportion). I updated all the audio drivers and the problem aren't my headphones since with other devices is the same.

Comment: Try *Troubleshooting > Troubleshoot audio playback*.

Comment: @harrymc [I did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5pf3.png)

Comment: I'm getting confused, as this is the 3rd post about this same computer. Check that your drivers and BIOS are [up to date](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X510UF/HelpDesk_Download/).

Comment: @harrymc I'm downloading BIOS, audio and VGA drivers but how do I install them?

Comment: Normally there should be executable files for that, and reboot to check. BIOS update is dangerous, so check if yours is already this version, and have good backups before starting. If the audio driver didn't help, delete the device in Device Manager and reboot, for Windows to install its own driver.

Comment: @harrymc I didn't update the bios since the current version was already that one. I installed the audio driver but the other 2 threads can't be resolved updating the drivers.

Comment: Usually when the solution is given in a comment, the right thing to do is to invite an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update the drivers from the [Asus official page](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X510UF/HelpDesk_Download/) and it's resolved.